# firebase child snapshot retrieval is not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, avcapturesession

I am writing a code for a barcode scanner that scans a barcode and search for the barcode in the firebase database. I am able to get the barcode working and i can retrieve the scanned barcode numbers but I running the barcode through firebase is not working. This is my code.

```
   if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            var productbarcode = metadataObj.stringValue
            messageLabel.text = productbarcode

            let catalogue = ref.child("UPC").child(productbarcode!)
            catalogue.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                print(value)

            }){ (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            print("Barcode detected")

        }
```

I want it to print the firebase node snapshot that matches the scanned barcode and if it can't find it print error. 

unfortunately it is not printing either the snapshot when there was one or the error message when it can't find one in the firebase DB. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: please show the structure of your firebase db